How to cluster time-of-day event data?
Suppose I have data about patient sneezes, e.g.,:
Name    Time   Loudness
Alex    07:59  10
Bob     08:03  12
Charlie 17:06  9
Alex    08:09  13
...

You can see that Alex and Bob mostly sneeze at about 8 and Charlie mostly at 17.
How do I "algorithmize" this?
I can summarize the data in, say, 5 minute (or 1 hour) intervals and use something standard (k-means or spectral), but this way I lose the "continuity" aspect (sneezes right before and right after 8:00 will go to different intervals and adjacent intervals are treated independently).

I would look into kernel density estimators. Once you have the KDEs you can run some other algorithm to determine your "clusters," e.g. find the peaks/modes. There are periodic KDEs as well so that way you can allow a sneeze at say 23:57 to be treated as similar to a sneeze at 00:05.

Interesting, thank you. Alas, (1) neither sklearn nor scipy have periodic KDEs and (2) neither support "weights" (Loudness) in my exmple.

Yes, I actually have dealt with a similar problem before and IIRC I had to do a custom implementation for the von Mises distribution. The math/code isn't necessarily hard, you just lose out on the numpy/scipy efficiencies and object-oriented features.
